# Regex fails to capture all groups

Tags: java, javascript, regex, capturing-group

Using `java.util.regex` (jdk 1.6), the regular expression `201210(\d{5,5})Test` applied to the subject string `20121000002Test` only captures `group(0)` and does not capture `group(1)` (the pattern `00002`) as it should, given the code below:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("201210(\\d{5,5})Test");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("20121000002Test");

if(m1.find()){

    for(int i = 1; i<m1.groupCount(); i++){         
    System.out.println("number = "+m1.group(i));            
    }
}
```

Curiously, another similar regular expression like `201210(\d{5,5})Test(\d{1,10})` applied to the subject string `20121000002Test0000000099` captures group 0 and 1 but not group 2.

On the contrary, by using JavaScript's RegExp object, the exact same regular expressions applied to the exact same subject strings captures all groups, as one could expect. I checked and re-checked this fact on my own by using these online testers:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html
- http://www.regextester.com/

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is it that Java's regex library really sucks?

Comment: If you add `/` at the beginning and end of your RegExp in JavaScript, it returns a single group. Are you really sure about what you're saying? Have you prepared your own JavaScript test for this (i.e. **no** online editors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m1.groupCount()` returns the number of **capturing** groups, ie. 1 in your first case so you won't enter in this loop `for(int i = 1; i<m1.groupCount(); i++)`

It should be `for(int i = 1; i<=m1.groupCount(); i++)`

Comment: Thank you folks for all the answers! I just cannot believe it. It never crossed my mind that groupCount() would not include group 0, unlike javascript's Regexp exec(). It does not make much sense for me because, after all, group 0 is a damn group! Anyway, I guess I should've debuged the code in more depth...

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
for(int i = 1; i<m1.groupCount(); i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i<=m1.groupCount(); i++){      //NOTE THE = ADDED HERE
```

It now works as a charm!

Comment: Thank you folks for all the answers! I just cannot believe it. It never crossed my mind that groupCount() would not include group 0, unlike javascript's Regexp exec(). It does not make much sense for me because, after all, group 0 is a damn group! Anyway, I guess I should've debuged the code in more depth...

Answer (score 0):

> the regular expression "201210(\d{5,5})Test" applied to the subject string "20121000002Test" only captures group(0) and does not capture group(1)

Well I can say I didn't read the manual either but if you do it says for [Matcher.groupCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount%28%29)

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.
>   Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

Comment: In java, group(0) means everything, and group(1) means first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= m1.groupCount(); i++) { 
                   ↑
              your problem
```

Answer (score 0):

From [java.util.regex.MatchResult.groupCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#groupCount%28%29):

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

So iterate through `groupCount() + 1`.

Comment: No, it's just `groupCount()`.  The problem is that he's only going up to `groupCount() - 1` now.

Comment: @Alan Same thing. It should be while `i < groupCount() + 1` or while `i <= groupCount()`. Arguing correctness beyond that is silly. (I favor the former because `<=` is easy to miss in loop conditions.)